# Automatically wrapping I-search?

Tags: search, emacs

In Vim I can `:set wrapscan` so that when I do an incremental search, the cursor jumps to the first match whether the first match is above or below the cursor.

In Emacs, if I start a search via `C-s`, the search fails saying *Failing I-search* if the first match is above the cursor.  If I hit `C-s` again it then wraps the search, saying *Wrapped I-search*.  How do I wrap and jump the cursor by default as in Vim, without having to `C-s` a second time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the following defadvice:

```
(defadvice isearch-repeat (after isearch-no-fail activate)
  (unless isearch-success
    (ad-disable-advice 'isearch-repeat 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-repeat)
    (isearch-repeat (if isearch-forward 'forward))
    (ad-enable-advice 'isearch-repeat 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-repeat)))
```

When Isearch fails, it immediately tries again with wrapping. Note that it is important to temporarily disable this defadvice to prevent an infinite loop when there are no matches.

Comment: Thanks, I see how this is supposed to work, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The function isearch-no-fail doesn't exist in my Emacs.  I grepped all the Emacs source code and it's not in there.

Comment: isearch-no-fail is just a name of this defadvice, you can change it to anything you want. I tested this code in GNU Emacs 22 and GNU Emacs 23, and it works exactly as you described. Could you provide more details to understand why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Never mind, I don't know where my mind was.  It does work, but it was slightly different than what I wanted.  I wanted it to wrap the search as I typed, without hitting C-s again at all.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution has the annoying side-effect of requiring you to hit backspace twice to remove the first character that fails to match.

Comment: A bit new to emacs here. How do you execute this function in a keymap? I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'isearch-no-fail)` but I get 'Wrong type argument' in mini-buffer.

Comment: You don't need to bind this function to a keymap. Just put it in your init file (e.g. ~/.emacs) or evaluate manually with `C-M-x` (eval-defun), and it will wrap I-search automatically.

Comment: @Hinrik To fix the problem where you have to hit backspace twice, add this to your config:   `(define-key isearch-mode-map [remap isearch-delete-char] 'isearch-del-char)`

Answer (score 8):

Jurta's answer got most of the way there. This is the wanted behavior:

```
;; Prevents issue where you have to press backspace twice when
;; trying to remove the first character that fails a search
(define-key isearch-mode-map [remap isearch-delete-char] 'isearch-del-char)

(defadvice isearch-search (after isearch-no-fail activate)
  (unless isearch-success
    (ad-disable-advice 'isearch-search 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-search)
    (isearch-repeat (if isearch-forward 'forward))
    (ad-enable-advice 'isearch-search 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-search)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `isearch-wrap-pause` to `no`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repeat-Isearch.html

Comment: "automatic wrapping happens only for repeated search and not incremental search" https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071338/588759. For incremental wrappping this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707038/588759

Comment: I just tested this out, and it looks like settings it to `no` will wrap around on the incremental search as desired in the question. It looks like the work was discussed in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=56535

Comment: This did not work while entering the search string itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53006) to be perfect for me (a former Vim user). It makes isearch work just like Vim. It enables automatic wrap-around as well as switching search direction with just one keypress of C-s / C-r