# emacs: How to stop search after file ending?

Tags: search, emacs

I somehow could not figure out how I can search in Aquamacs so that the search stops at the file end and does not "wrap around" (continuing from the file beginning).

If one steps through the search result, one could manually stop at the last item, but I typically step through quite fast so that I accidentally jump over the file ending and continue at the file beginning.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a variable `isearch-wrap-function` which is unset by default. Set it to an empty function and then it won't wrap:

```
(setq isearch-wrap-function (lambda ()))
```

You can also set it so that it throws an error and aborts isearch:

```
(setq isearch-wrap-function (lambda () (error "no more matches")))
```

Comment: nicely done.  That's a better answer than the defadvice hack.

Comment: Dear Tom, very nice, indeed! Do you also know how to set this "locally", so not by default but just for one particular search? And: Can something like this be done for search & replace as well? So when moving forward with <space> when using M-%.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.  It seems like such a terrible idea.  But apparently you aren't the first person to want this.  For the record, you can just un-wrap with C-r.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285660/automatically-wrapping-i-search) has an answer with defadvice that does that you want.

Comment: I know it's terrible. But I there are situation where it is useful. 
As far as I know, C-r just searches backwards, that does not solve the problem. I would like to use a forward search with C-s but if I hit CMD + G [apple for "find next"] long enough, it should stop at the last found string before the file ends (even if I hit CMD + G again a couple of times). The behavior now is that hitting CMD + G after the last found string, the cursor jumps to the file beginning and the search continuous. The same of course happens with C-r, just backwards.

Comment: I meant that if you detect you've wrapped to the top, you can just wrap back to the bottom with C-r.