# In Emacs, how to search in the whole file?

Tags: search, emacs

Consider the following text file:

```
foo
bar
yoo
ploo
```

Imagine that I want to search the word `foo` and that my cursor in in the third line. I use `C-s` which calls `isearch-forward`, then input `foo` and press `Enter`: the issue is that by default, my cursor stays at the same position, unless I press `C-s` once again before pressing `Enter`. Indeed, I would like `isearch-forward` to move in the whole file, and not only the part of the file that is after the cursor. How could I do this ?

Comment: You could try helm-swoop: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Helm-swoop it is an interactive way to search in the whole buffer. The more you type, the more it narrows its results in another buffer. You can cycle through the results without loosing context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible Duplicate:

[Automatically wrapping I-search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285660/automatically-wrapping-i-search)

Try this: (copied from the link above)

```
(defadvice isearch-search (after isearch-no-fail activate)
  (unless isearch-success
    (ad-disable-advice 'isearch-search 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-search)
    (isearch-repeat (if isearch-forward 'forward))
    (ad-enable-advice 'isearch-search 'after 'isearch-no-fail)
    (ad-activate 'isearch-search)))
```