# Setting isearch-wrap-pause in emacs 28

Tags: emacs, customization

I would like to customize the following variables that were newly introduced in Emacs 28.1.

- **isearch-wrap-pause** (defined with defcustom in isearch.el, default value *t*)
- **isearch-repeat-on-direction-change** (defined with defcustom in isearch.el, default value *nil*)

I have the following in my init file.

```
  (setq isearch-wrap-pause nil
    isearch-repeat-on-direction-change t)
```

I see the desired effect with this setting. But, I don't see the expected effect when setting **isearch-wrap-pause** to *no* or *no-ding* (other values as defined in isearch.el).

I've tried with

```
  (setq isearch-wrap-pause 'no
    isearch-repeat-on-direction-change t)
```

and

```
  (setq isearch-wrap-pause "no"
    isearch-repeat-on-direction-change t)
```

and

```
  (setq isearch-wrap-pause no
    isearch-repeat-on-direction-change t)
```

without success.

How do I set **isearch-wrap-pause** to *no* or *no-ding*?

**Edit [As on 2022-07-22]:**

The expected behaviour I was looking for was to wrap around automatically when searching  incrementally. I raised a bug with Emacs developers and they informed that this is not the intended behaviour, and automatic wrapping happens only for repeated search and not incremental search.

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=56535

Comment: Should there be no answer, maybe ask at <help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behaviour I was looking for was to wrap around automatically when searching incrementally. I raised a bug with Emacs developers and they informed that this is not the intended behaviour, and automatic wrapping happens only for repeated search and not incremental search

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's been developments in the thread that was linked in the question (https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=56535). It's now possible to `(setq isearch-wrap-pause 'no-ding)` or `(setq isearch-wrap-pause 'no)` to automatically wrap the search even if you're doing incremental searching (I'm using emacs 29, not sure if it's also on emacs 28)

Comment: Yep, as per the discussion, this feature is scheduled for release 29. I was waiting for the official release to convey the same here. It's not in version 28 (both 1 and 2).